# The boundary of set is the set itself examples

Tags: general-topology

Could you provide me some examples of sets, which are not based on Cantor's construction, that satisfy the property $\partial A=A$, that is the boundary of a set is the set itself?

Comment: The circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in the plane is such an example.   The set $\mathbb Z$ of all integers within the line $\mathbb R$ is another. $\qquad$

Comment: Any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m>n$ will work. E.g., a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a plane or surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, ...

Comment: Generally Jordan curves, compact sets of dimension less than the space.

Comment: @kccu Don't you mean, any *closed* subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @bof Yes, thank you. It's too late for me to edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any closed set with an empty interior is its own boundary. @MichaelHardy gave you two examples in his comment: the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in the plane and the set of $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers within the line $\mathbb{R}$. Also @kccu noted that you can take any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m > n$, like a line in the plane, or a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Since comments are ephemeral but answers are eternal, I think it would be a good idea to quote the comment in your answer rather than just refer to it.